# How to sync & increment a value within a Text Input when a numeric value is entered in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, counter, onchange

I have a counter button that decreases/increases the number in my text input by one. My counter is set initially to 0 and if i press the increase button it increases by 1. However if I delete the initial 0 and manually type in a number, the counter button will increment it to the value 1.

How do I fix this?

Also how do I prevent the number from going higher than 99 and less than 1 because the maxValue and minValue don't seem to be working.

**ShopAttack.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Badge } from 'native-base';
import {MaterialIcons as Icon} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import image from '../assets/Images/ShoeJackCityLogo.png';
import { ifIphoneX } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';


    import { commonStyles } from './styles/styles';

    class ShopAttack extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          counter: 0,
          isModalVisible: false,
          show: true,
      }
[![}][1]][1]

      IncrementItem = () => {
        if(this.state.tempNum){
          this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + this.state.tempNum, tempNum: null });
    }
      else{
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
      }
    }
      DecrementItem = () => {
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter - 1 });
      }
      ToggleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
      }

     handleOnTextChange = (text) => {
        const number = parseInt(text)
        if(number){
        this.setState({tempNumber: number})
        }
      }

      _toggleModal = () =>
      this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });


                    <View style={[commonStyles.row, commonStyles.alignSelfcenter]}>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.IncrementItem()}>
                        <View
                          style={[styles.counterButton]}
                        >
                        <Icon
                          type="MaterialIcons"
                          name="add"
                          size={40}
                          style={[
                            commonStyles.alignSelfcenter,
                            commonStyles.justifyCenter
                          ]}
                          />
                          <Text
                            style={[
                              commonStyles.inventrytextbutton,
                              commonStyles.white,
                              {}
                            ]}
                          >
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                      <View
                        style={[
                          styles.inventrybar,
                          styles.alignSelfcenter,
                          styles.row,
                        ]}
                      >
                        <Icon
                          type="MaterialIcons"
                          name="monetization-on"
                          style={[
                            commonStyles.font16,
                            commonStyles.alignSelfcenter,
                            commonStyles.ml15,
                            {
                              color: '#C8A74D'
                            }
                          ]}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                          keyboardType = 'numeric'
                          onChange = {this.handleOnTextChange}
                          maxValue={99}
                          minValue={0}
                          style={[
                            commonStyles.inventrybartextbutton,
                            commonStyles.redText,
                            commonStyles.ml5
                          ]}
                          >
                        {this.state.counter}

                        </TextInput>
                      </View>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.DecrementItem()}>
                        <View
                          style={[styles.counterButton]}
                        >
                        <Icon
                          type="MaterialIcons"
                          name="remove"
                          size={40}
                          style={[
                            commonStyles.alignItems,
                            commonStyles.justifyCenter
                          ]}
                          />
                          <Text
                            style={[
                              commonStyles.inventrytextbutton,
                              commonStyles.white,
                              {}
                            ]}
                          >
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
```

**Main Focus Point**

//When I enter a value inside the textbox(TextInput because this is react //native) the increment button does not increment the value I entered. I //could send you a screen recording/screenshot via email or something.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      counter: 0,
      error:''
    };
  }
//my code
 IncrementItem = () => {
    if(this.state.tempNum){
          let sum = parseInt(this.state.counter) + parseInt(this.state.tempNum);
          if(sum >=1 && sum <=99){
              this.setState({ counter: sum, tempNum: null });
          }else{
            console.log("Number should be between 1 and 99");
            this.setState({error:"Number should be between 1 and 99"})
          }

    }
  else{
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
  }
}
  DecrementItem = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter - 1 });
  }

  handleOnTextChange = (e) => {
         const number = e.target.value;
         console.log(number)
         if(number){
         this.setState({[e.target.name]: number})
         }
       }

  render() {
    return (
            <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.IncrementItem()}/>
                    <TextInput
                      keyboardType = 'numeric'
                      returnKeyType="done"
                      type="text"
                      name="tempNum"
                      value={this.state.tempNum}
                      onChange = {this.handleOnTextChange}
                      maxValue={99}
                      minValue={0}
                      >
                    {this.state.counter}

                    </TextInput>

                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.DecrementItem}>
                      style={[styles.counterButton]}
                    >
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I fixed the typo within my code from this.setState({tempNumber: number}) to this.setState({tempNum: number}) and added tempNum: null, to my state but I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a typo error in your code.

`this.setState({tempNumber: number})` should be `this.setState({tempNum: number})`

And you should define `tempNum` state in the `constructor` like

```
this.state = {
     tempNum: null
}
```

2. There is a react-native-numeric-input library that supports numeric input.

   https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-numeric-input

Comment: I fixed the typo within my code from this.setState({tempNumber: number}) to this.setState({tempNum: number}) and added tempNum: null, to my state but I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

**Some issue's are,**

You are setting `tempNumber` state variable

```
this.setState({tempNumber: number})
```

but accessing `tempNum` which is a typo here,

```
if(this.state.tempNum){
   this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + this.state.tempNum, tempNum: null });
}
```

Just change `tempNumber` to `tempNum` or vice-versa.

When you don't want to pass any value to function, don't do this,

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.IncrementItem()}>
```

you just need this,

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.IncrementItem}> // same for DecrementItem
```

Another issue is,

```
this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + this.state.tempNum, tempNum: null })
```

When you set a state, it is possible that state value is stored as string, so doing `this.state.counter + this.state.tempNum` might result in string concatination, you can do this,

```
this.setState({ counter: parseInt(this.state.counter) + parseInt(this.state.tempNum), tempNum: null })
```

Simplified [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a4mbam).

---

For preventing the number from going higher than 99 and less than 1,

```
IncrementItem = () => {
    if(this.state.tempNum){
      let sum = parseInt(this.state.counter) + parseInt(this.state.tempNum);
      if(sum >=1 && sum <=99){
         this.setState({ counter: sum, tempNum: null });
      }else{
        console.log("Number should be between 1 and 99");
        this.setState({error:"Number should be between 1 and 99"})
      }   
    }else{
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
    }
}
```

You can check same for `DecrementItem`.

Comment: I used your code but my TextInput is not accepting it. I know there isn't a difference but I'm using react native and you're using react.
<TextInput
                      keyboardType = 'numeric'
                      returnKeyType="done"
                      type="text"
                      name="tempNum"
                      value={this.state.tempNum}
                      onChange = {this.handleOnTextChange}
                      maxValue={99}
                      minValue={0}
                      >
                    {this.state.counter}
                    </TextInput>

Comment: There is no error. When I enter a value inside the textbox(TextInput because this is react native) the increment button does not increment the value I entered. 

I could send you a screen recording/screenshot via email or something

Comment: Just create a example here, if it is not running it's ok just want to check your code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react

Comment: You forgot to fork and then share. I can't see your code here.

Comment: Link is not opening.

Comment: Do one thing. Update your post, and add updated code. Don't delete previous post add extra edit section.

Comment: I added the extra section

Comment: Your problem is `onPress={() => this.IncrementItem()}` do this `onPress={this.IncrementItem}`

Comment: That's not the issue either. It's like any numeric value I type inside the TextInput is not hooked up or synced to the counter. If i type in 10 and press the increment button it will equal 1 because the initial value of the counter is 0.

Comment: Confirm that when you type in textInput, console from `handleOnTextChange` print correct value, also when you press `IncrementItem` button do `console.log(this.state.tempNum)` and check if it prints correct value.

Comment: It says undefined when I do a console.log(this.state.tempNum)

Comment: This means your `handleOnTextChange` function not storing data in state. Delete everything from that function and just have this `this.setState({tempNum: e.target.value})`.

Comment: **It's still saying undefined.**

handleOnTextChange = (e) => {
         this.setState({tempNum: e.target.value})
       }

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.IncrementItem(console.log(this.state.tempNum))}>

<TextInput
                      returnKeyType="done"
                      type="text"
                      name="tempNum"
                      value={this.state.tempNum}
                      onChange = {this.handleOnTextChange}
                      >
                    {this.state.counter}

                    </TextInput>

Comment: Why are you doing this `onPress={() => this.IncrementItem()}` you need to do this `onPress={this.IncrementItem}`

Comment: I did it just to do the console.log() and I cahnge my handleOnTextChange to handleOnTextChange = (e) => { this.setState({tempNum: e.target.value}) } and it still came up as undefined on the increment button

Comment: Just have `onPress={this.IncrementItem}` this much and console.log in `IncrementItem` function.

Comment: Still coming up as undefined. Can we try a teamview?

Comment: I found your mistake you need to do this `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}`, In reaact native we have `onChangeText` - Refer this - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html. Check the above link, I have update my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197192/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-masterolu).

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even with the code changes.